# iF statement evaluating true incorrectly

Tags: python, dictionary

`gridSystem` is a dictionary, and it's key is another dictionary containing an action and the value. My problem in the `action` function is the 2nd if statement. If `action` is not equal to one of the actions in dictionary `a` (Look, Boots.. these names are placeholders for now), it should just print out "Try again". But for some reason, it always evaluates to true no matter what, and gives me an error when I type in something that's not an action in the dictionary. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
a = {"Look":1, "Boots":32}


gridSystem = {"One":a}



def action():
    while True:
        room = raw_input("choose a room ")
        if room in gridSystem.keys():
            action = raw_input("What do you want to do? ")
            actiontoString = ''.join([action])
            if action == actiontoString:
                continue_action = raw_input("You have selected to " + actiontoString)
                print gridSystem[room][action]
                break
            elif not action == actiontoString:
                print "Try again"
        else:
            raw_input("Not in the gridsystem. Press enter to try again")



action()
```

Comment: A good debug technique is to print the variables just before the `if` statement to see if they hold the values you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`actiontoString = ''.join([action])` will, in effect, create an exact copy of `action` (which is a string) and save it to a reference called `actiontoString` (another string, exactly the same). That's always going to be `True`.

You probably need `if action in gridSystem[room]:` instead of the current equality check. Replace the `elif...:` with a simple `else:`. Use `print "You have selected to", actiontoString` instead of getting an unneeded input from the user.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks